# Why Reload button sending POST request ?, Flask Python

Tags: python, html, flask, web

I have created a sign-up page with username and password form inputs that send a POST request upon entering and I wish to send it to my database

But I see that even on clicking the reload button, a POST request is sent.

This is my python-flask code for the route

```
@app.route('/signup',methods=["GET","POST"])
def signup():
    return render_template('signup.htm')
    if request.method=="POST":
        password = request.form['password']
```

Is there an option to specify that clicking the reload button SENDS ONLY A GET REQUEST?

Answer (score 0):

First of all in your code, nothing will run after the return statement so the if statement wont run.

Secondly you should separate your functions. By this I mean that you should have a separate function for rendering the page and for handling the form response

Such as:

```
@app.route('/signup',methods=["GET"])
def signup():
    return render_template('signup.htm')

@app.route('/submitsignup',methods=["POST"])
    password = request.form['password']
    return 'Form submitted'
```

Comment: But what will be the HTML for /submitsignupc?

Comment: @BizTecBritain is right about the code after ```return``` not running. However, you don't have to separate functions. Keep your code but move ```return render_template('signup.htm')``` to the last line in your function. The logic then will be - function first checks if this is a POST i.e. user entered user name and password and it will process it, else it will just return the login page. We can't answer your original question unless we see the html page and the code you have for the reload button

Comment: There is no HTML for the reload button

Comment: You are right but when I do a                                                                                                if request.method =="POST":  password = request.form['password']  else : rendertemplate('THEHTMLFILE'[pseudocode]   and i click the reload button to update the changes , the reload button then sends  a freaking POST request to the   localhost server and then it checks for the password before the html has been rendered and hence raises an error

Comment: All of this would be avoided if the freaking reload sent a GET request as it normally would

Comment: And BTW the reload button is part of the browser